# Email gets queued in response of SMTP server; Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, next.js, smtp, nodemailer, email-client

I want to send transactional emails through my Next js website to users for Newsletter and resetpassword purpose, i am using Nodemailer with SMTP credentials.  used Mailgun, Sendinblue, MSG91, Postmark (all with the free plan) but either my mail goes to backlog or gets queued.

I also tried Sendinblue api but still got the same problem, none of the email got in the mailbox of the recipient. You can see the full response and API below;

**This is my API, skip the commented logic and jump to the nodemailer part**

```
import ConnectDB from "@/utils/connect_db"
import User from "@/models/user"
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

const forgotPassword = async (req, res) =\> {
try {

        if (req.method === 'POST') {
            await ConnectDB()
            // let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
            // if (!user) user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.email }) //because user can put the username or email in the same field and api should verify from both ways
            // if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ success: false, msg: "You don't have an account with this email!" })
            // const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '2m' })
    
            // USING Postmark
            const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: "smtp.postmarkapp.com",
                port: 587,
                auth: {
                    user: "34dd6ee8-8015-444a-92e5-25194cf742cc",
                    pass: "34dd6ee8-8015-444a-92e5-25194cf742cc"
                }
            });
    
            // create email message object
            const message = {
                from: 'binarshadsaad6@gmail.com',
                to: 'saad19rsf@gmail.com',
                text: "hellow this is a text email body to check the email service",
                subject: 'You subscribed our Newsletter',
                html: `<html><body><h1>Fitte Moooo!</h1><p>Dear valuable Jheengu this email is to notify you that you have successfully recieved the 'Fitte Moo' reward for literally just existing at this time of morning.</p></body></html>`
            };
    
            // send email using nodemailer
            let info = await transport.sendMail(message);
            console.log(info)
            res.json({ success: true, info })
    
        }
        else {
            res.status(400).json({ success: false, msg: "bad request, you are using wrong request method!" })
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, msg: "Internal server error occurred, pleae try again later" })
    }

}
export default forgotPassword
```

**And this is my full response when i hit the api**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "info": {
    "accepted": [
      "saad19rsf@gmail.com"
    ],
    "rejected": [],
    "ehlo": [
      "PIPELINING",
      "SIZE 20480000",
      "VRFY",
      "ETRN",
      "AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5",
      "AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5",
      "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES",
      "8BITMIME",
      "DSN"
    ],
    "envelopeTime": 622,
    "messageTime": 452,
    "messageSize": 858,
    "response": "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3B28D414C40",
    "envelope": {
      "from": "binarshadsaad6@gmail.com",
      "to": [
        "saad19rsf@gmail.com"
      ]
    },
    "messageId": "<50a33941-a951-b4eb-2290-781a58eda83d@gmail.com>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I work at Postmark and while I'm not technical enough to troubleshoot your code, I can offer some other insight: If you are on the Postmark free plan, you'll only be able to send emails to your own domain until your account is approved ([more detail on that here](https://postmarkapp.com/support/article/1084-how-does-the-account-approval-process-work)). Otherwise your emails would be queued as you see here. Our support team is also happy to help—you can reach them at support@postmarkapp.com.